# Please explain "set difference" in python

Tags: python, set

Trying to learn Python I encountered the following:

```
>>> set('spam') - set('ham')
set(['p', 's'])
```

Why is it `set(['p', 's'])` - i mean: why is `'h'` missing?

Comment: Why do you expect `h` to be *included*?

Comment: I thought it is to show the differences, so from my feeling I expected `h` to be included. Looks like I got the concept wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-` operator on python sets is mapped to the `difference` method, which is defined as the members of set `A` which are not members of set `B`.  So in this case, the members of `"spam"` which are not in `"ham"`are `"s"` and `"p"`.  Notice that this method is not commutative (that is, `a - b == b - a` is not always true).

You may be looking for the `symmetric_difference` or `^` method:

```
>>> set("spam") ^ set("ham")
{'h', 'p', 's'}
```

This operator *is* commutative.

Comment: I believe the statement *[The `^` operator] corresponds more to the mathematical notion of set difference* is misleading. It does correspond to the mathematical notion of *symmetric* difference, but not to the mathematical notion of set difference.

Comment: Ah, you're correct.  The mathematical notion of set difference, according to wolfram, is actually the `-` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Because that is the definition of a set difference. In plain English, it is equivalent to "what elements are in A that are not also in B?".

Note the reverse behavior makes this more obvious

```
>>> set('spam') - set('ham')
{'s', 'p'}

>>> set('ham') - set('spam')
{'h'}
```

To get **all** unique elements, disregarding the order in which you ask, you can use `symmetric_difference`

```
>>> set('spam').symmetric_difference(set('ham'))
{'s', 'h', 'p'}
```

Comment: You don't need `set('ham')` here - set methods take any iterable, so using `set('spam').symmetric_difference('ham')` is fine

Answer (score 2):

There are two different [operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

- **Set difference.** This is defined as the elements of A not present in B, and is written as `A - B` or `A.difference(B)`.
- ***Symmetric* set difference.** This is defined as the elements of either set not present in the other set, and is written as `A ^ B` or `A.symmetric_difference(B)`.

Your code is using the former, whereas you seem to be expecting the latter.

Answer (score 1):

The set difference is the set of all characters in the first set that are not in the second set.  'p' and 's' appear in the first set but not in the second, so they are in the set difference.  'h' does not appear in the first set, so it is not in the set difference (regardless of whether or not it is in the first set).

Answer (score 1):

You can also obtain the desired result as:

```
>>> (set('spam') | set('ham')) - (set('spam') & set('ham'))
set(['p', 's', 'h'])
```

Create **union** using `|` and **intersection** using `&` and then do the **set difference**, i.e. differences between **all elements** and **common elements**.