# Find the element "left" in a list

Tags: python, list

I have the list `list1 = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Ohai"]`.

I have another list, `list2 = ["Hello", "Goodbye"]`.

I want to get the remaining items in `list1`, in this case this would be `"Ohai"`.

Comment: You're still missing **what you've actually tried**, and what precisely the problem with it is; this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: Look up the documentation on difference between two lists or sets.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: also, you asked a question of the **identical** title like 5 minutes ago. You don't think *changing* and *rephrasing* might help it's clarity?

Comment: Generally, don't repost just because your last question was downvoted to oblivion. *Rethink*, *narrow down*, and then ask again.

Comment: Also, the needed answer can be extracted from quite a few SO questions, including [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204360/please-explain-set-difference-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> list1 = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Ohai"]
>>> list2 = ["Hello", "Goodbye"]
>>> set(list1) ^ set(list2)
set(['Ohai'])
```

If you are supposed to use lists only, you can iterate:

```
>>> [item for item in list1 if item not in list2]
['Ohai']
```

But why do that when you have sets ;-)

Answer (score 1):

this calls for Python `set`:

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
remainder_of_exclusion = set1-set2 # think like normal sets in math, set1\set2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through `list1` and `list2` combined and get `x` if it's not in both lists.

```
result = [x for x in (list1 + list2) if not (x in list1 and x in list2)]
```

Comment: just wanted to know is this will work? if list contains duplicates [i.e the frequency of a word is more than 1]

Comment: @YashMehta This method would include the duplicates in the new list, yes. If you used `{}` instead of `[]`, that would create a set instead of a list which would prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list1[len(list2):]
['Ohai']
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Works well, does exactly what's asked for.